# HTTP 500 error because setup:upgrade doesn't work

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I created a class and I can't understand why when I pass a second parameter give a error HTTP 500.

I'm trying to do a simple code, like this:

```
  namespace Ahimsa\FooterLinks\Block;

  use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template as Template;


class FooterLinks extends Template
{
 protected $_storeManager;
 protected $categoryRepository;
 protected $_categoryHelper;

 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper)
 {

    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    parent::__construct($context);
 }
}
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` after change the class?

Comment: Thank's @Piyush for the correct sintaxe.

Comment: Try clearing `var/generation` and `var/cache` folder

Comment: @EvgenyLevinsky, yes. I runned bin/magento c:c and php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: @Priyank, i runned `bin/magento c:c`. I think this clear `var/generation` and `var/cache`

Comment: No it will not clear `var/generation` folder. Clear it manually

Comment: What is error in your log-file `var/log/system.log`?

Comment: @Priyank, i used `rm -rf var/generation to clear`. No success.

Comment: @EvgenyLevinsky, to many errors in log, like this: `[2017-12-20 13:14:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []`. But when i remove second parameter it´s working fine.

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: I think at 2.2 you need to clear '/generated' folder instead

Comment: @harri, version 2.2. I did that!

Comment: Did that work? Other than that i would check actual php logs normally tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log then bring up the page and your 500 error page and will see an error show up.

Comment: In `use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template as Template;` remove the forward slash and just write it as  `use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;` clear cache and try again

Comment: I notice that is not the second parameter, because when i do `public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, $some_variable)` works fine. Don't Know why.

Comment: But I'm still with the problem because I need to use `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category`, but when i put in the constructor show me the HTTP 500 error.

Comment: can u plz show us apache error log latest error

Comment: I found the error :). I was executing magento commands inside cmd in Php Storm IDE. When I executed in Mac Terminal the command `bin/magento setup:upgrade `work's fine. Thank's guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error :). I was executing magento commands inside cmd in Php Storm IDE. When I executed in Mac Terminal the command bin/magento setup:upgrade work's fine. Thank's guys.